# Contesting or flagging an answer you know is wrong but was accepted

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, moderators, flagging

This particular question/answer has been around for two years now:

[Consuming Google Maps as background map through ArcGIS Server?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305/is-it-possible-to-expose-google-maps-as-background-map-through-arcgis-server)

It contains an answer that was accepted.  However, the answer is not the correct answer.  It's just plain wrong.

One of the more seasoned users posted this comment:

"This answer is still wrong. Google does not supply a WMS feed. Can either the author or a super-admin(?) update this? Its a very FAQ, and one that will appear in Google search results, and I dont want wrong answers being associated with gis.stackexchange."

Should there be a way to contest an accepted answer?  Or at least bring it to the attention of a moderator or super-admin?

Comment: I'm satisfied with the strong message sent by the community's voting on these answers. It clearly indicates the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: I just made a feature request on Meta SE that, if implemented, would I think resolve your issue on this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268666/timing-out-accept-status-on-answer-but-leave-points-with-its-poster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options, from strongest to weakest, include:

- Edit the answer.
- Provide an answer of your own specifically countering the accepted answer.
- Comment (politely) on the answer.
- Downvote the answer.

Any combination of these can be applied.

Moderators are not intended to arbitrate questions of fact or accuracy.  The expectation is that through the mechanisms outlined above, the community will clarify matters of factual dispute.

Comment: It looks like I need to point out that "edit the answer" does *not* mean inserting your own comments into an existing answer. It means changing it to be correct. In the present situation that's probably going to be difficult to do without changing it entirely. In many cases an edit works because an answer is wrong due to a typographical error, or a problem with a line or two of code, or some other such simple, obvious fix.